# Why is my code printing a blank line first?

Tags: java

I have a program that takes input from a text file and displays this    [image: 1]

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numLabels = 0;
    if(scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        numLabels = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error! Invalid input.");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    String[] label = new String[numLabels];
    int[] data = new int[numLabels];

    for(int i=0; i<numLabels*2; i++)
    {
        if (i<numLabels)
        {
            label[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }
        if (i >= numLabels)
        {
            if(scan.hasNextInt())
            {
                data[i-numLabels] = scan.nextInt();     
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Error! Invalid input.");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }   

    for(int i=0; i<numLabels; i++)
    {

        int width = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<label.length; j++)       
        {       
            if(width<label[j].length()) width=label[j].length();
        }

        String a = "";

        for(int j=0; j<data[i]; j++)
        {
            a = a + "*";
            if(j==(data[i]-1)) System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.printf("%" + width + "s  %s", label[i], a);
    }
}
```

It's doing what I want, but there's a blank line at the beginning. It's pretty minor but I want to know why it's showing up, both to fix it now and for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this line here:

```
if(j==(data[i]-1)) System.out.println();
```

Also, by putting the new line inside the loop, I think it will actually produce an incorrect result when you try to plot something with a count of 0.

If you want to get rid of it, print out the newline *after* each row of your bar chart:

```
String a = "";

for(int j=0; j<data[i]; j++)
{
    a = a + "*";
}
System.out.printf("%" + width + "s  %s\n", label[i], a);
```